# Plug-And-Play Blogging Engine?

Tags: blogs

OK, the title is a bit misleading I suppose, but only because I'm not really sure how to condense down what I'm looking for.

Currently, I have my own personal site that I've built which rests on a CMS that I also built. I wasn't really interested in blogging when I started the site (it was mainly to showcase my Android apps), so I only added basic 'blogging' features like posting news items and such.

As of late, however, I have taken a keen interest in blogging, and would like to pursue it on my website. The issue I'm having is that I don't particularly want to invest the time it would take to expand upon my CMS to include things like archives, comments, search, and all of the other various blogging-related features that are standard.

So what I'm looking for is a blogging engine that I can **plug into my existing site framework**. I have found tons of services that are platforms that you build on top of (i.e Wordpress, Chyrp, and TextPattern just to name a few) but that's not what I want. I'm looking for something that I integrate into my site, not something I integrate my site into (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

So you want a third-party application that can plug in to a proprietary custom-built blogging/CMS framework?  Unless you patterned your framework after some other publicly available and widely used framework then I think it is very unlikely that such a thing exists.

I'd suggest maybe seeing if there's a way to come up with a database migration script that will take the data that your custom framework is using and translate it into something that an existing blogging platform can understand.  Then just completely replace your custom platform with the prebuilt one.

Comment: OK, I probably described the issue a bit to... pompously.
I'm effectively looking for something that has the Wordpress theming support (take your markup, replace your static holder copy with PHP calls to various functions) without the entirety of the Wordpress backend.
My apologies for not being as clear.